# How to build my own TeXLive Distribution scheme?

Tags: installing, texlive

how can I build my own TeXLive Distribution scheme? I needed a special scheme for distributional reasons, which means to include only the packages needed and also for a better redistribution. To be more precise, we only use engines like lualatex, luatex and xelatex and their related packages. Also we use certain packages from different collections. It would nicer to build a scheme and not to install something "portable" and after that install different packages needed.

Comment: It would help if you clarify your requirements.  What exactly do you want to achieve?  Also, TeX Live mailing list is where you are likely to get the best answer to your question.

Comment: There's a lot more to TeX Live than just packages. The TeXLive installer has a portable option which can produce a minimal distribution for use on e.g. a USB stick; maybe that might be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to just make an installation with everything you need in it and then zip it up and distribute that.  For integration with the system on win32 (PATH, menu shortcuts, file associations) you can use [w32client](http://www.tug.org/texlive/w32client.html).  You can even combine everything into a simple exe installer using [7zip](http://docs.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/sfx.htm) or something similar, all depends on your needs and how much effort you're willing to put into this.